# Access specific public datasets in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to follow the following tutorial on Energy Forecasting in GCP. (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/machine-learning/solutions/energy_price_forecasting)

In particular, I'm trying to access the data which seems to be available as a public dataset in BigQuery.

```
Raw data for this problem is publicly available in BigQuery in the following tables:
energy-forecasting.Energy.MarketPricePT - Historical hourly energy prices.

energy-forecasting.Energy.historical_weather - Historical hourly weather forecasts.
```

However, my BigQuery only has the following public datasets.

```
Public Datasets
bigquery-public-data:hacker_news
bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod
bigquery-public-data:samples
bigquery-public-data:usa_names
gdelt-bq:hathitrustbooks
gdelt-bq:internetarchivebooks
lookerdata:cdc
```

How can I access the desired data?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `energy-forecasting` project into your UI

> To add a project to the Classic UI:

Click the down arrow icon next to your project name in the navigation panel.

In the drop-down menu, click Switch to project > Display project.

In the Display Project dialog:

Enter the project ID.
Leave Display project in navigation panel selected.
Click OK to add the project to the navigation panel.

see details [`here`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-classic-ui#adding_and_removing_projects)

> To add public project in New Web UI - use url like below

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=energy-forecasting

Then, you can [`pin project`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#pinning_adding_a_project) so next time you go to new Web UI - it will be there for you.

Comment: If I click on the drop down with the project names, it just gives me all the project names available to me. There is not option to "switch to project" or "display project"

Comment: Are you in classic or new ui?

Comment: You might be in new ui, so see URL to be used in my answer